Heroku Postgres database records gone after about 24 hours
I have deployed application in Spring Boot on heroku server, but after about 24 hours all records in the database are gone. All tables are still there.
Maybe I shoud create new Postgres addon again with other parameters?

Do you have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set?

@Slevin yes, set to: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

@Slevin Maybe I should change to update and upload app again?

Very good thinking, since your application otherwise will reset the db everytime it gets restarted. Usually you don't wanna have even that option in place for production but none instead and create your db once, either old school or via tools like Flyway or Liquibase.

@Slevin Looks like it helped!  Now it is changed to update
